# User owns/manages other users

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have table `Users` with `ID`, `username`, `password` & `type` columns. I'd like to add hierarchy by making a regular user, a superuser who can manage a few regular users. It's only 2 level.
Should I add a `parent` column and save the ID of the superuser there. Idk.

What's the proper way to setup this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advocate keeping this as simple as possible, so I think your solution is a good one.  A `parent` column will get the job done.

There are potential problems that you can solve at the application level, specifically:

- Parents of super user parents
- Cycles

When adding a parent, you will have to check that the user is not already a parent.  You can also periodically check for cycles, although they shouldn't be possible as long as you enforce the other check properly.

Another fairly simple solution that would prevent these issues would be to have another table, let's say `Groups` that had the group's ID and a user ID that was the super user for that group and also unique.  Then a user could have a groupID column.  This prevents both of the issues above, but it is not normalized since a super user could have a different groupID column than the group's super user ID column.  You can simply ignore the groupID column for super users, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that each user will only ever have one superuser associated with them, and that you'll always search from users to superusers, then just adding an extra `parent` column will work.

If those assumptions don't hold, then you'll want to create a join table that joins users to their parents.

```
CREATE TABLE UserParents (
  id INT,
  user_id int,
  parent_user_id int,
)
```

`user_id`, and `parent_user_id` are both foreign keys to `Users`.